# Upload large size file more than 2 GB. What will be the best approach?

Tags: c#, azure, file-upload, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2

I want to upload large size file which is more than 2 GB to Azure data lake / blob storage.

I tried with the Azure's cloud blob method PutBlockListAsync.
ref: https://www.andrewhoefling.com/Blog/Post/uploading-large-files-to-azure-blob-storage-in-c-sharp

I will check with the grpc.

What are the different approaches I can try out to improve the performance while uploading such huge files?
-With chunk upload
-Buffered upload
-GRPC
-AZCopy
-Any other technique or Hybrid technique

Comment: You can also try using a combination of the approaches to improve the performance of the upload. For example, you could use chunk uploads and gRPC together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **[Azure data movement library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-data-movement-library)** to upload larger files to file share or blob storage.

*I tried in my environment and got below results:*

**Code:**

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement;

class program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string storageConnectionString = "<Connection string>";
        CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("test");
        blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
        string sourceBlob = @"C:\Users\download\sample.docx";
        CloudBlockBlob destPath = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("sample.docx");
        TransferManager.Configurations.ParallelOperations = 64;
        // Setup the transfer context and track the download progress
        SingleTransferContext context = new SingleTransferContext
        {
            ProgressHandler = new Progress<TransferStatus>(progress =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Bytes Upload: {0}", progress.BytesTransferred);
            })
        };
        // upload the blob
        var task = TransferManager.UploadAsync(
        sourceBlob, destPath, null, context, CancellationToken.None);
        task.Wait();
    }
}
```

For workaround I took a file with 100 mb to upload files using above code, also you can also use the **`chunk uploads and GRPC`** method together said by Nour.

**Console:**

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

You can also use  **[Azcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-copy)** for uploading large files in datalakestorage.

Comment: My application type is not console app, its an web API. Above solution loading a file from local path whereas I want solution in which client can upload file and server/backend API will get in stream. Can you please consider this scenario.